# Using C runtime library functions only

Tags: c++, stl

This is most likely a stupid question, but I cannot make heads or tails of my professor's notes, so here goes:

I have an assignment to write a function in C/C++ that takes an array and sorts all instances of 0 to the back of the array. However, I am only allowed to use the C standard runtime library, not the STL or any other templated containers. I'm not entirely sure how to use the runtime library (it's my first advanced programming class and I've only ever worked in C++ before).

Do I have to include or use a namespace for the runtime library?

Is including `<iostream>` for C++ breaking those rules?

How about using the C++ standard library? I know it's not the STL, but I am unsure if it counts as a "templated container".

Comment: "C/C++" is not a language. You may want to find out which one you should use first.

Comment: *"I have an assignment to write a function in C/C++"* Facepalm. *"I know it's not the STL"* While this is correct, I find it unlikely that your prof knows that.

Comment: Just use the bare language and don't #include anything except for your own headers.

Comment: @Jongware: I don't think his instructor cares. The limits appear to be on the libraries used.

Comment: Templated algorithms are not templated containers, so that part doesn't forbid use of `std::sort()`...

Comment: Btw, the algorithm you want to implement is called "partition" and is implemented as [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) in the C++ standard library. The link above provides a simple example implementation.

Comment: Sure, if you don't mind an F, go ahead and try to outsmart your prof in the definitions game.

Comment: Since you are using **C** / C++, I suggest you compile as the C language because the C language doesn't have namespaces. nor the STL.  This will reduce your confusion level.

Answer (score 3):

Professors tend to get a bit sloppy here. I am almost certain that you can use the standard library for console I/O, such as iostreams or `*printf`.

It's almost certain that he justs want you to avoid using functions like `qsort` or `std::sort` for your assignment, as that would take away the value of learning and implementing the algorithm.

As long as you implement your assigned sort manually over an array, you should be fine.

Of course the safest bet is to double-check with your professor, but I'm pretty sure this is what he/she means.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the c library function (xxxxx.h) you don't include any namespace as they import into the root namespace.

To perform the actual sort, no library functions are needed at all, although I can think of one that can be adapted (qsort).

To input and output, you will need C stdio (see stdio.h) for at least fgets and fputs; although in this case scanf and printf might be easier if you don't have to handle input typos. If you've only ever done C++ before this will be a back-to-basics moment to get simple IO working. C stdio is easy. It's also easy to make really bad mistakes in.